# Netbeans profiling points not working

Tags: java, netbeans, profiler

i am following the instructions in this article
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/profiler-profilingpoints.html#02b
'Measuring Execution Time of a Code Fragment'
i followed exactly the instructions. in step 9 the profiling point should be hit but mine doesn't get hit 
i am using the latest version of netbeans

Comment: i tried using netbeans 7.4 and it worked is it possible that the latest version   has still problems?